# How to delete media file from res/raw folder?

Tags: android

I have a media file under my `res/raw` folder and after the app installed I need to delete this file. How to do it?

I know that I can download this file after install and then delete or any other ways, but I need this file to be build. I see only option to make it build in put it to `res` folder. But because of size 100Mb I don't wan't to hold it, so I need to remove it.

I am not sure that it is even possible

Comment: It's not possible. It's no longer a file after it's been packaged into the apk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to do it?

That is not possible. Resources and assets are packaged in the APK and are read-only. They cannot be modified or deleted.